# org-mode completions within latex fragment

Tags: org-mode, completion, preview-latex

### Problem

In `org-mode 9.6.6` when not in a LaTeX fragment, inserting `\` and invoking `completion-at-point` produces a multitude of LaTeX completions.

Doing the same thing when in a LaTeX fragment, I would like the same completions to be available, but they are not.

### What I have figured out so far

`completion-at-point-functions` contains `(pcomplete-completions-at-point t)`, and the definition of `completion-at-point` is as follows:

```
(defun completion-at-point ()
  "Perform completion on the text around point.
The completion method is determined by `completion-at-point-functions'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((res (run-hook-wrapped 'completion-at-point-functions
                               #'completion--capf-wrapper 'all)))
    (pcase res
      (`(,_ . ,(and (pred functionp) f)) (funcall f))
      (`(,hookfun . (,start ,end ,collection . ,plist))
       (unless (markerp start) (setq start (copy-marker start)))
       (let* ((completion-extra-properties plist)
              (completion-in-region-mode-predicate
               (lambda ()
                 ;; We're still in the same completion field.
                 (let ((newstart (car-safe (funcall hookfun))))
                   (and newstart (= newstart start))))))
         (completion-in-region start end collection
                               (plist-get plist :predicate))))
      ;; Maybe completion already happened and the function returned t.
      (_
       (when (cdr res)
         (message "Warning: %S failed to return valid completion data!"
                  (car res)))
       (cdr res)))))
```

When not in a LaTeX fragment, `res` is being bound to the same value as the result of `(pcomplete-completions-at-point)`; when in a LaTeX fragment, `res` is bound to `nil`, even though `(pcomplete-completions-at-point)` returns the same value as before.

Comment: I can not reproduce it here. Are you sure you are trying to complete equal 'patterns'? If so, could you add examples?

Comment: It works in a `\begin{math}...\end{math}` environment, but not in `$...$` or `\(...\)` or `\[...\]`. If I run `completion-at-point` with point immediately after the second of the three backslashes in the following text: `\(\\)`, it says `No Match`. If I do it like this `\( \ \)` it says `cl--assertion-failed: Assertion failed: (<= start (point))`. This is all done in `/tmp/x.org` after `emacs -Q` while using `emacs-mac`

Comment: Please report your findings with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. I can reproduce the assertion failures. You should also add the Org mode version you are using to your question.